# How to clear text from a text box in Tkinter | Python 3.6

Tags: tkinter, textbox

I am having problems with removing the text in the 'labelresult' text box. I have tried to use some solutions i found on Stack Overflow but they didn't work. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

def encrypt():
    encrypted = ""
    encCode1 = str(encCode.get())
    try:
        encNum1 = int(encNum.get())
    except ValueError:
        labelresult = Label(myGUI, text="You did not use a number please try again").grid(row=7, column=2)
    if (encNum1 == 0):
        encNum1 = randint(-38,4)
    for letter in encCode1:
        if letter == " ":
            encrypted += " "
        else:
            encrypted += chr(ord(letter)+encNum1)
    labelresult = Label(myGUI, text=encrypted).grid(row=7, column=2)

myGUI=Tk()
myGUI.geometry("700x300")
myGUI.title("Encrypter/Decrypter")

encCode=StringVar()
encNum=StringVar()

label1=Label(myGUI,text="Use the two boxes under this text to Encrypt", fg="red").grid(row=0,column=2)
label2=Label(myGUI,text="Enter the code to be encrypted").grid(row=2,column=0)
label3=Label(myGUI,text="Enter a number between -38 and 4 to encrypt with").grid(row=3,column=0)

myn=Entry(myGUI,textvariable=encCode).grid(row=2, column=2)
mys=Entry(myGUI,textvariable=encNum).grid(row=3, column=2)

button1=Button(myGUI,text="Calculate Encrypted Code",command=encrypt).grid(row=4,column=0)

myGUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Like any other object in python, you have to keep a non-local reference to an object if you want to manipulate it after it's created. This isn't a tkinter thing, it's just how python works.

Comment: BTW: common mistake `var = Widget().grid()`,  you assign `None` to `var` because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` returns `None`. You have to do in two steps `var = Widget()` and `var.grid()`, or in one `Widget().grid()` if you don't need `var`

Comment: `labelresult` is local variable which exists only inside function till you exit function. You have to create global variable - it means outside function - ie. `labelresult = None` and inform function to use this global variable using `global labelresult` in function.

Comment: BTW you can create label at start and later only change text - `labelresult["text"] = ...`